# Hide the div class when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have list of videos which I want to hide the class of it when I click it. Here is the sample html output of it.

```
<div id="primary-video">
    <iframe id="video" width="100%" height="auto" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/test" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
    <div class="primary-video-details-wrap">
        <div class="primary-videotitle ">Primary title</div>
        <div class="primary-videodatepublished"> Published on Jul 15, 2016</div>
        <div class="primary-videodescription"> testing</div>
        <div class="comment-wrap">
            <div class="fb-comments fb_iframe_widget_loader fb_iframe_widget fb_iframe_widget_fluid fb_hide_iframes" id="fb-comment" data-href="https://facebook.com/test/posts/test" data-width="100%" data-numposts="10" fb-xfbml-state="rendered"><span style="height: 100px;">
                <iframe style="border: none; overflow: hidden; height: 100px; width: 100%;"></iframe>
                </span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="video-list">
<div class="video-list-wrapper" style="display: block;">
    <div class="video-wrap">
        <div class="left-video-info"><a href="#null"><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/hqdefault.jpg" alt="Video" width="100%" height="auto"></a><span class="video-duration">10:03</span></div>
        <div class="right-video-info">
            <div class="video-title">The video 1</div>
            <div class="video-date">24 days ago</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="video-list-wrapper" style="display: block;">
    <div class="video-wrap">
        <div class="left-video-info"><a href="#null"><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/hqdefault.jpg" alt="Video" width="100%" height="auto"></a><span class="video-duration">05:19</span></div>
        <div class="right-video-info">
            <div class="video-title">The video 2</div>
            <div class="video-date">25 days ago</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="video-list-wrapper" style="display: block;">
    <div class="video-wrap">
        <div class="left-video-info"><a href="#null"><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/hqdefault.jpg" alt="Video" width="100%" height="auto"></a><span class="video-duration">05:52</span></div>
        <div class="right-video-info">
            <div class="video-title">The video 3</div>
            <div class="video-date">25 days ago</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

How can I hide it when there is already a click function on the class `left-video-info`

The click function is to change the primary video and details.

```
$('.left-video-info').on('click',function(event){
  var rownum = $(this).index('.left-video-info');

 $('#video').attr('src','https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+video_information_array[rownum].video_info_link);
$('#fb-comment').attr('data-href','https://facebook.com/test/'+video_information_array[rownum].video_info_fb);
                          $(primary_published).text(video_information_array[rownum].video_info_date);
                      $(primary_des).text(video_information_array[rownum].video_info_description);
                      $(primary_title).text(video_information_array[rownum].video_info_title);

         $(".page-content").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 400);
           return false;
});
```

**Update issue**: I forgot to include the function of my load more button: The class that I have clicked was hiding(its good), But when I click the load more function. The hiding class will appear again. Is there a way it will no appear unless the page reloaded?
Here is working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xkevin/h2hegehv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind multi-click event on a element:
e.g.

```
$('.left-video-info').on('click', function(){
    //TO DO #1
}).on('click', function(){
    //TO DO #2
}).on('click', function(){
    //hide self
    $(this).hide() // or $(this).toggle();
    //hide parent 
    $(this).closest('.video-list-wrapper').hide()
})
```

Comment: Thank you!  But I have issue on my load more function.

Comment: When I try to click the class it will hide. But when I load more video the video I was cliked before was there. Is there a way It would not appear unless the page reload? here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xkevin/h2hegehv/

Comment: A solution with CSS:
`<style type="text/css">
    .hidden { display: none;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.left-video-info').on('click', function(){
        $(this).addClass('hidden');//add a class for the item need to hide
    })
})
</script>`

Comment: Sorry, please try this one:
'<style type="text/css">.hidden { display: none !important; } </style>'

Comment: Awesome solution.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your question but

to hide a div on click should be as easy as

```
jQuery(".class-of-div-that-is-clicked").click(function(){
    jQuery(".class-of-div-that-gets-hidden").hide();
});
```

to remove a class when the div is clicked can be done by

```
jQuery(".class-of-div-that-is-clicked").click(function(){
    jQuery(".class-of-div-with-classes-to-be-removed").removeClass("class-to-be-removed");
});
```

of course you need to change ".class-of-div-that-is-clicked" and "class-of-div-that-gets-hidden" etc. to the appropriate names